# Error linspace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype' only in windows

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pip, canopy

I have a script that I run on Red Hat 4.4.7 with success:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.9.1'
>>> numpy.linspace(3,4,5,dtype=int)
array([3, 3, 3, 3, 4])
```

While on my windows installation, even after updating numpy (pip install -U numpy), I get an error:

```
In[3]: import numpy
In[4]: numpy.version.version
Out[4]: '1.9.1'
In[5]: numpy.linspace(3,4,5,dtype=int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\lb\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-5-cce2ab26cfad>", line 1, in <module>
numpy.linspace(3,4,5,dtype=int)
TypeError: linspace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

Why this different behaviour? What else should I check beyond numpy version?

EDIT:

```
print(repr(numpy.core.function_base))
<module 'numpy.core.function_base' from 'C:\Users\lb\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.pyc'>

print(repr(numpy.__path__))
['C:\\Users\\lb\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy']

print(numpy.linspace.__module__)
numpy.core.function_base
```

At line 8 of C:\Users\lb\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py I have:

```
def linspace(start, stop, num=50, endpoint=True, retstep=False):
```

So, I guess I messed up with the pip update...

Comment: You have something weird going on.  The `dtype` argument was added to linspace in 1.9.0 -- can you show the output of `print(repr(numpy.core.function_base))`, `print(repr(numpy.__path__))`

Comment: Also, can you open the .py file corresponding to what's shown in the first print statement in a text editor and see whether the `dtype` keyword argument is present? (e.g. `def linspace(start, stop, num=50, endpoint=True, retstep=False, dtype=None):`)

Comment: FYI, you can easily print the source in the shell: `import inspect; print(inspect.getsource(numpy.linspace))`. Or using some IPython magic: `numpy.linspace??`.

Comment: *So, I guess I messed up the pip update* -- well, something got messed up.  Trying to update numpy through the repositories requires a valid and configured C toolchain.  Since you're on Windows, you might try downloading the precompiled wheel from Christoph Golke's site [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and installing with `pip install <path to downloaded wheel>`

Comment: I tried a couple of times, also renaming the file  and changing the folder,   but I get ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', './numpy-1.9.2.whl', 'at', '/numpy-1.9.2.whl") Note that in the homepage he says "Chances are they don't work with custom Python distributions included with [...] Canopy". Unfortunatey Canopy package manager has only numpy1.8